# 403 when using addFirebase API to add firebase to a Google Cloud Project with cloud-platform oauth scope

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am having some troubles working with the google cloud APIs, in my application I have the auth scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" but I am not able to perform an action to the API that adds Firebase capabilities to an actual project https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/firebase-management/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase.

I get a 403:

```
{
    error: {
      code: 403,
      message: 'The caller does not have permission',
      status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED'
    }
}
```

The token is valid, I am the owner of the project, etc.

Everything else works greate, it's just this firebase-management APIs that give me trouble.

For context, I am trying to create automatically a firebase project.

Any clue?

I tried adding as a second scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase", and that works, but the documentation clearly states:

*Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase*

Answer (score 0):

That response is the intended behavior. As documentation clearly states that:

> Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase

That would depend what type of authentication you are using. If you're using the Cloud Identity and IAM as authentication then you should be using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`. Otherwise, if you're using the Firebase Auth then you should be using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase` instead.

---

You may check out this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#firebase) for OAuth 2.0 Scopes.

Comment: Thanx for your response. I was using Cloud Identity and IAM. And now it seems to be working.